# Long Tap on application icon and show popup menu

Tags: flutter, dart, popup

In my **flutter application** i want to make a feature, when user install my application and l**ong tapped on it,s icon** a **popup menu** appear so that the user can be transferred to specific pages of the application as a shortcut like in `Chrome` app, like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will help you [link](https://pub.dev/packages/quick_actions)

Some of the functionality need platform-specific code and hence you need plugins for that.